# Como filtrar um objeto json com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filtro, filter

Eu tenho o seguinte objeto json:

```js
var json = {
   "tpAmbiente":null,
   "hotelPesquisa":[
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":94,
            "nome":"Itamarati"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":95,
            "nome":"copacabana"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":96,
            "nome":"Itamarati"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":96,
            "nome":"Litoral Hotel"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":1001.00,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":1001.00,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};
```

Como faço para filtrar esse objeto para que so mostre os hoteis onde o preço for maior quem 100 e menor que 900?

O preço fica em:

```
hotelPesquisa[].quarto[].quartoUh[].tarifa.vlDiariaTotal
```

Retorno que preciso:

```
"hotelPesquisa":[
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":94,
            "nome":"Itamarati"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":890.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":890.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":95,
            "nome":"copacabana"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "dtEntrada":"20170510",
         "dtSaida":"20170511",
         "hotel":{
            "id":96,
            "nome":"Itamarati"
         },
         "quarto":[
            {
               "quartoUh":[
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 1,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":890.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
                  {
                    "nQUarto": 2,
                     "tarifa":{
                        "vlDiariaTotal":890.21,
                        "desconto":null
                     },
                     "qtDisponivel":null,
                     "desconto":null
                  },
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

Existe alguma maneira eu posso filtrar o objeto com jQuery e manter todas as propriedades? Obrigado!

Comment: Queres remover os quartos que estão fora do preço ou manter os quartos mas retirar o hotel onde nenhum dos quartos está dentro do preço?

Comment: E possível fazer dos dois jeitos? Mas acho que e melhor retirar o hotel

Comment: É possivel tirar hoteis e quartos, é isso que procuras?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Em alguns casos preciso tirar os hotéis e tem outros caso que preciso tirar os quartos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analiza onde está a array que queres filtrar e qual o elemento de comparação. A partir daí a lógica é a mesma que esta outra pergunta/resposta tua.

Neste caso precisas de repetir a lógica uma vez que queres filtar em dois niveis:

```js
var pesquisa = {
  min: 100,
  max: 900
};
var hotelPesquisa = [{
    "dtEntrada": "20170510",
    "dtSaida": "20170511",
    "hotel": {
      "id": 94,
      "nome": "Itamarati"
    },
    "quarto": [{
      "quartoUh": [{
          "nQUarto": 1,
          "tarifa": {
            "vlDiariaTotal": 890.21,
            "desconto": null
          },
          "qtDisponivel": null,
          "desconto": null
        },
        {
          "nQUarto": 2,
          "tarifa": {
            "vlDiariaTotal": 890.21,
            "desconto": null
          },
          "qtDisponivel": null,
          "desconto": null
        },
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "dtEntrada": "20170510",
    "dtSaida": "20170511",
    "hotel": {
      "id": 95,
      "nome": "copacabana"
    },
    "quarto": [{
      "quartoUh": [{
          "nQUarto": 1,
          "tarifa": {
            "vlDiariaTotal": 0, // este é gratuito!
            "desconto": null
          },
          "qtDisponivel": null,
          "desconto": null
        },
        {
          "nQUarto": 2,
          "tarifa": {
            "vlDiariaTotal": 102.1,
            "desconto": null
          },
          "qtDisponivel": null,
          "desconto": null
        },
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "dtEntrada": "20170510",
    "dtSaida": "20170511",
    "hotel": {
      "id": 96,
      "nome": "Itamarati"
    },
    "quarto": [{
      "quartoUh": [{
          "nQUarto": 1,
          "tarifa": {
            "vlDiariaTotal": 890.21,
            "desconto": null
          },
          "qtDisponivel": null,
          "desconto": null
        },
        {
          "nQUarto": 2,
          "tarifa": {
            "vlDiariaTotal": 10000.21, // este é muito caro!
            "desconto": null
          },
          "qtDisponivel": null,
          "desconto": null
        },
      ]
    }]
  }
];

var filtrados = hotelPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {
  hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh = hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh.filter(function(quarto) {
    return quarto.tarifa.vlDiariaTotal < pesquisa.max && quarto.tarifa.vlDiariaTotal > pesquisa.min;
  });
  return hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh.length > 0;
});

console.log(filtrados);
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!! Desculpa qualquer coisa. Ajudou muito.

Comment: @NewTech ótimo!

Comment: sabe o que pode ser?
 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203698/ajuda-com-filtro-javascript

Comment: @NewTech apagaste a pergunta. Encontraste a solução?

Comment: Ainda não. O meu problema e o seguinte. Preciso que o filtro me retorne o um json com todos os hoteis onde os preços dos quartos sejam maior que 0 e menor que 1010 com valores definidos manualmente em um array ele filtra normal mas quando utilizo o slide range ele não filtra. ele começa a filtrar quando desliza o slide range mas depois começa a retornar so [] como mostra [NESSA IMAGEM](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/sssssssssssssss-png--3) o link do JSFiddle olha no console https://jsfiddle.net/newtech/xrkuoqhq/2/

Comment: @NewTech aqui na Suécia onde vivo já é tarde por isso vou dormir. Mas amanhã estou por aqui. Coloca uma pergunta que eu respondo se ainda ninguém tiver respondido :)

Comment: na mensagem que eu envie a cima tem o link de uma imagem e do código no jsfiddle e eu recuperei a pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203698/ajuda-com-filtro-javascript