# Ajuda com filtro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, filtro

Tenho o seguinte código JavaScript:

**JSON**

```
var json = {
       "tpAmbiente":null,
       "hotelPesquisa":[
          {
             "dtEntrada":"20170510",
             "dtSaida":"20170511",
             "hotel":{
                "id":94,
                "nome":"Itamarati"
             },
             "quarto":[
                {
                   "quartoUh":[
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 1,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 2,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "dtEntrada":"20170510",
             "dtSaida":"20170511",
             "hotel":{
                "id":95,
                "nome":"copacabana"
             },
             "quarto":[
                {
                   "quartoUh":[
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 1,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 2,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":102.1,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "dtEntrada":"20170510",
             "dtSaida":"20170511",
             "hotel":{
                "id":96,
                "nome":"Itamarati"
             },
             "quarto":[
                {
                   "quartoUh":[
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 1,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 2,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":157.21,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "dtEntrada":"20170510",
             "dtSaida":"20170511",
             "hotel":{
                "id":96,
                "nome":"Litoral Hotel"
             },
             "quarto":[
                {
                   "quartoUh":[
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 1,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":1001.00,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                      {
                        "nQUarto": 2,
                         "tarifa":{
                            "vlDiariaTotal":1001.00,
                            "desconto":null
                         },
                         "qtDisponivel":null,
                         "desconto":null
                      },
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    };
```

**Função**

```
function filtro(min, max){
    var pesquisa = {
      min: min,
      max: max
    };
    var filtrados = json.hotelPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {
        hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh = hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh.filter(function(quarto) {
            return quarto.tarifa.vlDiariaTotal  dados.min;
        });
        return hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh.length > 0;
    });
    console.log(filtrados);
}
```

Eu utilizo o Jquery UI o slider range que o código e:

```
$("#price-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    values: [ 0, 1000 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        tjq(".min-price-label").html(ui.values[ 0 ]);
        tjq(".max-price-label").html(ui.values[ 1 ]);
        filtro(ui.values[ 0 ], ui.values[ 1 ]);
    }
});
```

Quando eu arrasto o slider ele chama a função filtro passando os parametros min e max para poder filtrar o json com os valores minimos e maximos do slider.
no começo ele ate filtra mas depois que arrasto o slider varias vezes ele retorna vazio:

```
[]
```

[image: imagem do console]

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

[Exemplo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/newtech/xrkuoqhq/2/)

As resposta aparece no console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o valor da array estava a ser sobreposto em `hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh = hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh.filter(...`.

Usando

```
var filtrados = json.hotelPesquisa.filter(function(hotel) {
    var quartos = hotel.quarto[0].quartoUh.filter(function(quarto) {
        return quarto.tarifa.vlDiariaTotal < pesquisa.max && quarto.tarifa.vlDiariaTotal > pesquisa.min;
    });
    return quartos.length > 0;
});
```

já funciona bem (https://jsfiddle.net/xrkuoqhq/4/). Mas para manteres a parte que filtra quartos também há alternativas diferentes, uma delas pode ser criar clones assim: https://jsfiddle.net/xrkuoqhq/5/